# Mod-rewrite lock execution of PHP files and access to .git folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to use mod-rewrite block execution of all files except for my bootstrap.php file in the document root, and I also want to block access to all files in the .git folder (also in the document root). Another (probably better solution) would be to allow access only files inside of a directory called public (there are multiple directories called public in different parts of my application), deny direct access to any other file while directing all other requests through my bootstrap.php file. Here's what I have.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* /bootstrap.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -fd
RewriteRule .*\.php /denied.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -fd
RewriteRule \.git /denied.php
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are NOT allowed to use multiple verification on a condition for files, it would give you an error like `bad flag delimiters`, if you use it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-fd
```

So it would be something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# not a existent file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and not a folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# and not a symbolic link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# and not bootstrap.php or denied.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(bootstrap.php|denied.php)$
# redirect to /bootstrap.php
RewriteRule .* /bootstrap.php

# is a existent file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
# or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
# or symbolic link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
# and not bootstrap.php or denied.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(bootstrap.php|denied.php)$
# contains .php or .git + anything else redirect to /denied.php
RewriteRule \.(php|git)/?.*$ /denied.php
```

You can also use the `F` flag instead which returns a 403 FORBIDDEN response to the client browser.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(bootstrap.php|denied.php)$
RewriteRule \.(php|git)/?.*$ - [F]
```

Comment: Looks better than what I had. (What I had was still showing the contents of the .git folder and attempting to execute the php files.) But I'm getting an internal server error for the /denied.php file. Here are its contents `<?php echo 'Access denied.';`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @RyanWilliams check the error_log it may tell you more about the error.

Comment: Actually, I think it's still executing the PHP files because I can still read out of the .git directory (even when I changed the rule to `RewriteRule \.(php|git) /denied.php`.

Comment: see the update try adding `/?` after the parenthesis as you might be accessing `.git/`. and remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !bootstrap.php$` just to make sure it will redirect or try to.

Comment: Okay I tried that, but it looks like there's a redirect loop. Here's the error `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.`

Comment: @RyanWilliams check it now

Comment: There it is. Thanks for the help. I hope this question will be use for to others.

Comment: @RyanWilliams you will also have to add verification for folder on the bootstrap or it will fail for .git, see update and indeed you cannot use `-fd` if breaks the rule.

Comment: Good catch. Thanks again. I decided just to return a 403 status.

Comment: @RyanWilliams that's the best way specially for spiders.

Comment: Yep, they're there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Common way how to restrict access to some folder is to put own .htaccess file into that folder and into that file use this code

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
```

This prevents the whole folder (and all folders inside that folder) from accessing (from the web/internet).

So I guess if you would use this in the main folder and modify it so it would allow only one folder where you would store all the "publicly accessed files" (like images and .css for example), it would be the best solution for you.

You can allow one folder like this

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow /onefoldername
Deny from all
```

This should prevent anything but folder named "onefoldername" from accessing from the web.

Comment: I know I can do that, but the problem is that I have a large directory structure and I'd prefer not to have a million .htaccess files. It would be hard for me to believe that there is no way to accomplish that in one file.